# How to bail out from PollingConditions.within timeout period?

Tags: groovy, spock

I have `PollingConditions` that probes system for some numerical value to have some exact value, e.g.:

```
def pollingConditions = new PollingConditions()
def status = 5; 
         ..... //schedule change of status in some background task
        pollingConditions.within(10,{
        //when status is 20, test must fail right away as it will never become 10 by the business rules
           assert status == 10;
        })
```

Now it is OK to wait until `status==10` unless status becomes e.g. `20`, in which case it is impossible for it to fulfill the assertion as defined by some status transition rules. In this case waiting for full period of 10 seconds makes no sense and I can fail the test right away.

How can I fail the test immediately in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PollingConditions` constructor without parameters sets a default delay of 0.1 s and a timeout of 1 s. I.e., your call will not wait the full 10 s but only 0.1 s in between iterations. That should be good enough for your purpose.

for more fine-grained control, you may use sometime like

```java
PollingConditions pc = new PollingConditions(timeout : 3, delay : 0.2, factor : 1)
pc.eventually { /* ... */ }
```

or simply use the setters on the instance created without constructor parameters.

Here are the source code of

- [class `PollingConditions`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/spock/util/concurrent/PollingConditions.java),
- [a test showing you how to use it](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-specs/src/test/groovy/spock/util/concurrent/PollingConditionsSpec.groovy).

BTW, if you statically type your `PollingConditions` instance, you no longer need to use `assert` and can just use normal Spock conditions. So either, you directly use `new PollingConditions().within(/* ... */)` or, like in my example above, declare the variable as `PollingConditions pc` instead of `def pc`.

---

**Update** after clarification in the comment: Just to show you how absolutely trivial it would have been for you to provide a full reproducer, I am going to provide one to prove that your "I cannot" is nonsense:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76919522

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import spock.util.concurrent.PollingConditions

import static de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76919522.PollingConditionsWithExitConditionTest.StateMachine.State.*

class PollingConditionsWithExitConditionTest extends Specification {
  static class StateMachine {
    enum State { AWAKE, SLEEPING, DEAD }

    State state
  }

  @Unroll("wake up from state #state")
  def "state machine must wake up before timeout"() {
    given:
    def stateMachine = new StateMachine(state: state)

    expect:
    new PollingConditions().within 10, {
      [AWAKE, DEAD].contains(stateMachine.state)
    }
    stateMachine.state == AWAKE

    where:
    state << [AWAKE, SLEEPING, DEAD]
  }
}
```

As for the problem at hand, the workaround for bailing out from the polling condition is very simple: Just test for both conditions, the one you are actually waiting for (in my example `AWAKE`) and the one that should bail out (in my example `DEAD)`. Then simply add another condition to re-check the `AWAKE` condition.

The effect is just what you want: The test terminates quickly for `AWAKE` and `DEAD` but waits the full 10 seconds for `SLEEPING`:

[image: test result from IntelliJ IDEA]

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJyNUl1rwjAUfe-vuLiXdkiYwjYUhcksY-wDwQ0fhows3tZgm3RJagXxvy9t6kdxD760zT0n55x7aEbZisYICySaqTz9Tqk2qIg2FpBrVFEiC_J7f9fr9G67Xc_jaSaVAZ1JtiIJFTGZZsh4xBk1XIp_8E-hZJI0gdzwhDApWK4UCkMmlsFF_CjFgpcy-mhkrC67NN-50IybZbjh5jD5QG3I1KriG2VLLtAdyLXnsYRqDZdJAG4MioWGxvqw9WAf2amdOlUoAIo8dXPYwmg2egnbMH0Nw8nz-1MbxuFoDDuvYjpSqYf2XA0fXJ1-q6ArhDyDSMnUUeCqerUCS1tgBC03TWvzNLep97d-MJIKwfAUZW5aflBni_kaRb_6LCX0afohCCwaC_kV3ne0wGXGjS3EOImSf1anH5DCNsoFdG7atS3AV11Euf68_DUM5ZZ7GoDUNiV9Vz3PURgOXaUuTLFEhf0jFwaDg1Oz8nlV8M77AznFBiQ).

Comment: I was not clear enouight i think. The point is, that after n-th probe for status value, you might be certain that assertion will NEVER succeed and in such case there is no point of keep probing. In my example (just arbitrary one), success condition is to have status of value 10, but due to state machine constrains, status 10 will never happen after status 20 therfore test can fail right away.

Comment: Its like having states for a person -`AWAKE, SLEEPING, DEAD`.
lets test `goToSleep()` method and probe for that person state change to SLEEP like `assert SLEEPING==state`. There is no need to keep probing if at some point you will probe state and you will get `DEAD` so w can fail the assertion (and whole test) right away.

Comment: That's the problem with incoherent sets of snippets instead of a full, minimal, reproducible example. Why don't you just provide one instead of ambiguously explaining what your code does theoretically?

Comment: Simple, I cannot.

Comment: Please note my updated answer.

Comment: I also added some information about how you can easily avoid having to use `assert` in your polling condition.

Comment: "Cannot" was regarding acutal code, MRVE would be possible, i just didnt do it, thought that problem is clear enough.

Comment: ok so your suggestion is to instead of polling for expected condition I can poll for condition change and assert afterwards. That will fit my need - thank you. However it is not an universal solution (due to possibility of N states in between). I think I will file a request to accept bail out exception in polling conditions.

Comment: I will even try to issue a PR :)

Comment: I do not think that a PR makes any sense, but feel free to. And I do think that my solution is universal. It does poll for the expected condition! It just polls for the bail-out condition on top of that. It should always be trivial to formulate such a combination, no matter how many states there are. You are only interested in the polling and the bail-out ones. If there are too many of either, your test is probably testing too much, or it is a sign that you should refactor the code under test. P.S.: Nowhere did I ask for your actual code. I asked for a minimal reproducer.

Comment: You are right I think, I just didnt see that at the first place. Thanks your your valueable input.

Answer (score 0):

While @kriegaex answer works, I wanted to mention that you can just return from a closure. This way you can separate the bailout from the normal conditions and save yourself the trouble to put them all into a one liner.

```
import spock.lang.*
import spock.util.concurrent.PollingConditions

class ASpec extends Specification {
  def "hello world"() {
    given:
    def bailout = true
    def x,y,z = 0

    expect:
    new PollingConditions().eventually {
      if (bailout) return
      // actual conditions
      x == 1
      y == 2
      z == 3
    }
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eJxlj8tOwzAQRff-iquuElS5PHZIWVT8ABJfYJxJGDHYkR80Keq_E6cWILGw5HPmembMH5MPCXHy9l2LcaO-UfzX5cSirXc2h0Au6Wcvwm588q7nxN5FpayYGHF8mciC5kSujyjAA1tTMvhSQE8Ddm8k4nHyQfpd024eGPmT3ON2LaFXw-JzQocUMv3oeb_sz6u83QzN64B0feTohH9rNa2mtW3KRmSpgwAe0NT-LQKlHFytHA4wtqRhf792Lc3oOtxVWArcVzgXeNjgosq5qG_ws2Y2).

Comment: This looks more elegant superficially, but your feature method is not equivalent to mine. For the bail-out condition not to unintentionally make the test pass but to only save time, as specified in the OP's question and in my own answer, you would still have to repeat the conditions after the closure, just like I did.

Comment: Sure, I mainly wanted to show how the bailout works. You can either test for the conditions again or test for `!bailout` afterwards.